# SQL server How to get the difference between 2 column from two different table?

Tags: sql-server

I need to find the difference between 1 column in 2 different table.

Example:
I have the table A with the Column 1 and i have the table B with the column 1 and 2.

```
A.1  /  B.1  /  B.2
---------------------------
100  /  100  /  2018-09-09
200  /       / 
300  /  300  /  2018-09-09
```

I want the query to show me  the row with the value 200 and the value 2018-09-09.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried?  Look up inner joins will give you the answer

Comment: I get that `200` is missing from B, so you want to show it. But where does the `2018-09-09` come from? Is this about interpolating data? What should it become if `B.2` equals `2018-09-12` for the last row of B in this example?

Comment: If b.2 is equal  another date i dont want to show it  so i would like this to be in the query like we will usally do  select * from  where B.2='2018-09-09' but i need to know what number from B.1  have no value for this date

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @A table(c1 int)
    insert into @A 
        select 100 union
        select 200 union
        select 300

declare @B table(c1 int, c2 date)
    insert into @B 
        select 100, '2018-09-09'  union
        select 300, '2018-09-09'

select *
from @A a
    left join @B b on
        b.c1 = a.c1
where b.c2 = '2018-09-09' or b.c2 is null
```